# when a div is not displayed, forget this css rule

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a situation where I have 3 divs : 
- Menu - Header (#rt-top-surround)
- Showcase (#rt-showcase)
- Main Body content (#rt-mainbody-surround)

The Menu is 'sticky' with position: fixed. Therefor I have to move the div that is rendered below it with padding (padding-top: 120px; margin-bottom: -120px;).

The problem that I run into is that on some pages the second DIV is #rt-mainbody-surround. (Than this div is rendered properly.) 
But on other pages I have #rt-showcase (that displays some promotional images) as second DIV followed by the main body DIV.

So what I would need to implement is a rule that not adds the padding & margin on the rt-mainbody-surround div when the rt-showcase is displayed. And I'm not wether to do this with Javascript or with PHP and how to accomplish this.

I've made an illustration to show what I exactly mean.

Hope anyone can help me out here! Thanks!

[Illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpFDJ.png)

Comment: have you tried just with a `padding-top: 120px` applied on `body`?

Comment: have a look at the `+` selector. Can be used for siblings so if sibling doesn't exist rule won't activate ( bit of an over simplification but close)

Comment: can you provide fiddle?

Comment: The problem is that on certain pages the 2nd DIV is not displayed. (I only use that 'rt-showcase' on the homepage.) In that case just this div needs the padding/margin. (So the third div does not need the padding/margin as it will shift the content 120px which doesn't look nice...) On all the other pages the 'rt mainbody' is the second div because the 'showcase' is not displayed. Only in this situation I want the padding & margin added to this 'mainbody' because than the menu would overlap the content.. I hope I could explain it clearly.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly you want a margin below a specific div *only* if another div isn't actively visible. The best way to handle this is to add a bottom margin to the top div and negative margin to the div below it (that can be shown and hidden). The css for that is:

```
.top {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.middle {
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```

Sometimes a picture is worth more than some code though so I created a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujtndo5v/2/). Enjoy!

Comment: That is a very nice example! However it is not what I mean. The top (menu) layer is around 120 px. This is 'fixed' so it 'scrolls along' with the page. There are two possible divs that can be below this menu, and because of the 'fixed' behavior of the menu I will have to move that down 120 pixels. On some pages I have have 'DIV2' as first below the menu so it needs the padding/margin. DIV3 is positioned below DIV2 on those pages so than it does not need any padding/margin as it would shift the content. On other pages I have only MENU and DIV3. In that situation I need the margin and padding

Comment: on DIV3, as that would than be rendered below the menu and else it would be cut off. In other words : If DIV 2 is present Div 3 does not need the padding/margin. If DIV 2 is not present than DIV 3 does need the padding / margin.